# What goes into the Model/Viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

what goes where?

This is a short description of my C# project:

I have a mechanical construction (only one in the whole program), described by some 20 to 30 parameters (deimensions, material parameters etc.), that may, as a complete set, come from an input screen or from an XML file (Deserialized). These parameters must then be processed in a calculation to generate output, that goes to a JPEG file and also to an HTML file.

The View is clear: it's the IO screen.

The View needs an ViewModel where the Properties are. Maybe:

My Model is the construction at hand, that is described by its parameters.
Those parameters however, are the same ones that are gathered from the IO screen , the View or from XML.

Some output (the JPEG file) also goes the View. It might be a Property that Notifies it's changed.

Now my question is, do I need a Model at all, because the ViewModel has all the properties already.

Or, do I need a ViewModel at all, because my Model has all the Properties to be Viewed. I could define a Model in the ViewModel (like it is always done in MVVM) and use the Model as a DataContext for the View. But that last option would make the View aware of the Model: not in the MVVM spirit.

Answer (score 7):

I've written this multiple times already, but I'll do it once more...

The main reasoning behind MVVM is to separate layers and to avoid tight coupling as much as possible.

That said, `View` is, as you've correctly guessed, the UI. Things your user sees. It doesn't matter if it's a Windows, a Page, a custom control, webpage or even a console (when we talk about MVVM in a broader context).

`ViewModel` is a mediator between your model and the view. It takes, combines and manipulates your methods and properties from the model for the purposes of the View. It doesn't care how, when and where are these used. It also can trigger actions on the model side, for instance call services that take care of updating your database.

`Model` is EVERYTHING that isn't tied to the specific platform. It's classes of your business logic, it's database entities etc. It's basically your application stripped of any ties to the UI implementation. This is what people get wrong and think that model are only database entities. That's simply wrong!

---

To answer the question you've asked: *"Now my question is, do I need a Model at all, because the ViewModel has all the properties already."*

Yes, you should, otherwise you'll end up coupling the view directly to the model and that's violating MVVM principle. Your View shouldn't know ANYTHING about the model directly. As far as View cares, every one of the properties and methods can be coming from a different project. It won't change a thing and the view will still function the same.

You maybe don't see it yet, but in the future it will make your life much more easier. The code becomes easily maintainable if done correctly, much more readable etc.

Comment: In a Youtube instructional video I saw a guy do a binding in his XAML like this: "{Binding Model.CustomerName}". That's a view "knowing" about the Model, right?

Comment: @Erik, yes. It directly binds to the specific object inside the viewmodel and even though he used the viewmodel, he probably used binding right to the model itself which is not a good idea most of the time. Much better would be to create a property that would propagate the property from the model, for instance `public string MyProperty { get { return someModelObject.SomeProperty; }}` Then you'd bind to this property of the viewmodel, and not to the property of the model directly, so you'll have this nice separation.

Comment: @Erik, many people don't do MVVM correctly. This guy you mention might have done that just for the sake of simplicity of the video, I don't know.. Technically you can do it like this and in simple applications be even totally fine doing so. However, as the complexity of the application rises, you can find yourself in so much trouble very soon. It's your call though... Just be aware of possible problems and limitations of the solution you choose.

Comment: @Erik, well, it's not really the same thing. The model can be re-used as a standalone component. The ViewModel stands between your core application and the UI. It can have data validation, get the values from multiple places, combine them, parse, whatever... As far as the View cares, it doesn't matter. The fact you currently don't need it doesn't that much matter, because in the future you'll have to probably refactor your code. What if your model changes, migrates or whatever, but the overall UI doesn't? Suddenly you have to refactor not only your ViewModel, but the View as well.

Comment: @Erik .. even if you just change a property name on the model. The viewmodel is that layer that really separates the model from the UI. You can in some later point think it would be a good idea to create a mobile application or a web application. If you bind directly to the model, there's a big chance you'll end up putting stuff to the model, that is really specific to the concrete UI implementation and shouldn't be there.

Comment: First: Thanks for your comments. Appreciated. Then: So I have to weigh the probability of model changes, migrations, to decide how I use MVVM.
I have been reading up on MVVM these last few weeks and get a fuzzy picture, an indeed often misused paradigm, differing opinions and what not. I get the idea that MVVM is rather "Business oriented": most if not all the examples are about accounts, customers, databases etc. That is not so in my case. In my case it's just  the digital model of a construction (properties and functions), and output a few numbers/graphs.

Comment: @Erik, if you want to follow MVVM 100%, you should use a ViewModel. World won't collapse if you don't, but... :) Examples are about accounts, customer etc., because it's the easiest way of showing things. More complex scenarios are kinda difficult to explain.. The problem is that people usually can't tell what changes they'll have to do to their code later on. MVVM makes the code a little bit more maintainable and testable, so if implemented correctly, it should provide a better code.

Comment: @Erik, if you have just a simple application, try to experiment with it a little and you'll see what works for you the best :) You can refactor at any time, just try to be consistent throughout your application, so it won't end up a big mess in the end.

Comment: In our application we do have a quite large data model. We wanted to change to MVVM (we were using WinForms before). So we ended up with dublicating 90% of the properties of the model into the view model. The view then most of the time was just routing the data into the model. So we stared with a clear seperation between model and viewmodel (as you proposed), but eventually were just using the model in the view because we just had so much code dublication which gave us not so much benefit

Comment: @walther I'm slightly confused by your answer. Could you elaborate on the next problem? I am using a datagrid to enter codes and prices. It needs validation as no code can be the same. I'd implement INotifyDataErrorInfo, but I feel that you'd oppose that, because for being platform-specific or containing things (error messages) that are too view-related. I could implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in a ViewModel, but I do also need the same validation logic in my model (right?), as not wanting duplicate codes in my database is not platform-specific. I'd be glad to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of what @walter said, you can check this Codeproject entry which explains flawlessly the difference and a little bit more. That article helped me to undestand when I was beginning:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

Comment: I always read that the Model has the "Business Logic". 

Then I read in your URL:

"Business logic is typically kept separate from the model, and encapsulated in other classes that act on the model".

ummmmmm.........


And: Do I have Business Logic at all?

Comment: @Erik in the next paragraph that you mention the author says: "is is not always true: for example, some models may contain validation." To achieve the cleanness of the Model we use helpers or Business Logic Data Handler Projects, You should only retrieve data in the Model. That's what the author means with "encapsulated in other classes that act on the model". Long strory short, for heavy business logic, use helpers or separate libraries and then reference them on the Model. I hope I could be clear...

Answer (score -1):

In short:

**Model**: A class that represents data, it shouldn't do anything. It's good practice to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, however it's not required if you don't need to change the data from the View.

**ViewModel**: A class that exposes the model as a public property so that the view can bind to it. It should contain methods that interact with the model. It could also contain properties of it's own.

**View**: Binds to the ViewModel, where it can access the model, and ViewModel properties.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Model is much more than a POCO/DTO/Entity class.

Comment: But: do I have data? Certainly no DB. OK, i can read from an XML file, but that I do in a Read-Command (part of the VM). Seems logical to me. The XML goes directly into the Properties that need to go into the VIew. No Model here... I'd say.
Also the calculation (a large part of the code) is a Command and can be done there, all on the Properties, generating a picture that goes into the View. No data here.... no Model either.... I's say.